# Hooking mouse input and moving cursor

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm setting up a global mouse hook:

```
hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, LLMouseProc, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);
```

and hooking all mouse move messages and moves mouse cursor.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LLMouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LPMSLLHOOKSTRUCT lpmh = reinterpret_cast<LPMSLLHOOKSTRUCT>(lParam);
    UINT             nMsg = static_cast<UINT>(wParam);
    POINT            ptScreen = { 0 };

    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        ptScreen = lpmh->pt;
        if (WM_MOUSEMOVE == nMsg)
        {
            // ptScreen coordinates we receiving are in physical units (pixels)
            // convert them to logical
            POINT logPos = { ptScreen.x, ptScreen.y };
            ConvertPhysicalToLogical(&logPos);

            // Move mouse cursor to the new position
            // SetCursotPos() requires coordinates in logical units
            SetCursorPos(logPos.x, logPos.y);

            // We don't want to propagate this message
            return 1L;
        }
    }
    return 0L;
}
```

Everything is works perfectly if scale factor is 1.0... Ok how it works. We move mouse to physical coordinate [29,94], let say, our scale factor is 1.5, so logical coordinates are [19,62]. We call

```
SetCursorPos(19, 62);
```

It triggers sending WM_MOUSEMOVE and somewhere internally converts our logical coordinates into physical 19 * 1.5 = 28, 62 * 1.5 = 93, so our new input coordinates now are [28,93] instead of [29,94]. Now we're repeating everything, converting [28,93] to logical [18, 62] and call

```
SetCursorPos(18, 62);
```

and so on...

So, I know that calling SetCursorPos() from LLMouseProc isn't correct and I'm trying to find a solution - is there any proper way to do it?

P.S.> ClipCursor() doesn't help because it also calls SetCursorPos()

Thank you!

Comment: i am not sure if it will work for you, but you may try `ClipCursor`

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and, of course it's a kind of proper way to move cursor, but it also uses logical coordinates and triggers SetCursorPos() which causes the same issue :(

Comment: What's the problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: I want to prevent my window from receiving any mouse messages, but I want mouse cursor behaves as usual.

Comment: Just make your window ignore mouse messages.

Comment: Good point, but I can't do that.

Comment: @Tutankhamen: Why not? It is your window afterall, right? In any case, what makes you think you have to convert the coordinates at all? `lpmh->pt` is in screen coordinates. `SetCursorPos()` takes screen coordinates as input. No conversion needed. Why are you scaling?

Comment: @Tutankhamen: Another thing to try, use `mouse_event()`/`SendInput()` to move the mouse, and then have the hook reject anything that does not have the `LLMHF_INJECTED` or `LLMHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED` flag on it. Or utilize the `dwExtraInfo` field when calling `mouse_event()`/`SendInput()` and have your hook look for that value in the `dwExtraInfo` it receives.  Then you won't scale your already-scaled movements, they will pass through as-is.

Comment: @Remy Lebea: We talking about conversion between logical and physical units, not about screen and client coordinates.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: Thank you for tip. Will try to play with mouse_event()/SendInput()